# missing R Data Editor window with RStudio on Mac

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I am learning R with RStudio on Mac. When trying the following code:

```html
mydata <- data.frame(age=numeric(0),
                     gender=character(0), weight=numeric(0))
mydata <- edit(mydata)
```

if I use R(GUI) on Mac, it works fine.
[R data editor popup from R on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxtXx.png)
But if I run the same code from RStudio on the same Mac, there is no window and the RStudio is stuck.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

R studio doesn't support edit function. Instead you can use library like 'editData' (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/editData/README.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On Windows system, RStudio can show the Pop up editor window.

Comment: I was wondering that my XQuartz doesn't work well. R on Mac is not using XQuartz, while RStudio does. Since Mac OS upgraded to 10.15, some applications cannot. Work anymore. XQuartz has not been updated for years

Comment: Reinstall the same version of XQuartz doesn't help.